# What does `!` mean in systemd's ExecStartPre?

Tags: systemd

! invokes history expansion, !! re-executes the previous command.

```
cat  /lib/systemd/system/motion.service
ExecStartPre=!/bin/mkdir -p /var/log/motion
```

With same logic,`!/bin/mkdir -p /var/log/motion` means to re-execute the `/bin/mkdir -p /var/log/motion`,it is meaningless.
How about write as `ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /var/log/motion`?
What does `!` mean in `!/bin/mkdir` ?

Comment: You've tagged your question `bash`, but afaik the syntax of the systemd service file is unrelated to that of bash's history expansion - it's one of the *Special executable prefixes* under [Command lines](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Command%20lines) in the systemd.service documentation.

Comment: In history expansion, `!/bin/mkdir` would mean to find the latest command that starts with `/bin/mkdir` and reuse it. The other args would just be appended. Try e.g. `echo foo`, `!echo bar`. Not that I've found much of use for it, but it's not meaningless. Of course it's not history expansion in systemd

Answer (score 5):

It prevents any `User=`, `Group=` and `SupplementaryGroups=` settings in the same `*.service` definition from affecting the `mkdir` command.

Apparently, the service file is designed to start the actual service process (`motion` I guess) as some non-root user. But since the `/var/log` directory is normally only writeable by root, the service file first runs `mkdir -p /var/log/motion` as root (and probably then assigns it to the user running the service?) to create a log directory for the service if it does not already exist.

So I would expect a pattern like this in the service file:

```
[Service]
User=motion
ExecStartPre=!/bin/mkdir -p /var/log/motion      # but this runs as root
ExecStartPre=!/bin/chown motion /var/log/motion  # also this
ExecStart=/usr/bin/motion                   # only this runs as "motion"
```